# Backing Up from command prompt

Tags: xcopy

I am trying to backup my system from the command prompt as windows will not boot.  I only want to backup documents but i am trouble with the command.

I am using "xcopy c:\documents and settings*.doc f:\Backup" and get and error saying the file is not found.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

You need to put the source in quotation marks because there is a space in the path name:

**xcopy "c:\documents and settings\*.doc" f:\backup**

The Robocopy equivalent would simply be:

**robocopy /s "c:\documents and settings" f:\Backup *.doc /r:0 /dcopy:t**

"/s" ensures it works on all the subfolders- not just the root directory (but ignores empty subfolders). The "/r:0" switch avoids it getting stuck if a file is locked- you can always run the task again if it reports any copies "failed" in the summary at the end. The "/dcopy:t" switch will preserve the various file timestamps.

Works a treat- I just tested it.

I just realized we made an assumption that all your documents are in the old Word format (.doc)

If you want ALL documents, you should add these file extensions (and perhaps others) too:

***.docx *.pdf**

Comment: better yet, try robocopy since it hasn't been deprecated like xcopy...

Comment: I agree- Robocopy is more flexible and properly supported. Plus it has some powerful features, even a switch for maintaining timestamps (/dcopy:t)

Comment: i've tried robocopy but got similar results, any suggestions on what i would need to type for robocopy

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: Ok just testing it now

Comment: it is doing something now dan.  I'll let you know if successful when it is finished

Comment: I just tested it and it worked beautifully. I'll change the first switch from "/e" to "/s" in my answer so it works on subfolders but ignores empty ones. No one cares about empty folders in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Use **XXcopy** instead of xcopy, you can get it from [here](http://www.xxcopy.com/xcpydnld.htm) it's free for home use.

```
xxcopy "c:\documents and settings\*.doc" f:\backup\ /S
```

Comment: Could you elaborate *why* to use XXcopy instead of xcopy?

Comment: many features, such as process sub-folder ( with filters, in this case *.doc) and ability to make exact directory structure on destination and also ability to make flat structure with no folder structure in destination. check http://www.xxcopy.com what is section for more info about xxcopy